# How to Save Shape Key Animations

Tags: animation

I have a couple shape key animations, but they don't seem to be saving properly. It's just a couple facial expressions, blinking, happy, angry. I can see it on the dope sheet,
[image]
But for some reason it doesn't seem to save them as an animation and I can't see any key frames on the action editor. If I press play, it plays the blinking animation, but if I click new action, and make another animation, the blinking animation seems to be overwritten? Also, when I export to fbx and import to Unity these animations are gone. I was able to export one shape key animation successfully, but upon importing again, it poofed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like shapekeys have their own Shapekey Editor in the Dope Sheet: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89421/where-are-the-keying-sets-keyframes-in-the-dope-sheet ... I do'nt know about the exportation though

Comment: Yeah, I can see/edit them in dope sheet, but they still don't save.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I was able to find the shape key editor, but no idea on how to save them for importing to unity. I don't understand it, I successfully imported one, so it's clearly not impossible. I wish Blender was easier to work with lol

Comment: it looks like if you google Blender shape keys Unity you'll have some answers?

Comment: I've googled that, of course haha. I didn't really find anything. Weirdly enough, I just tested an import, and there's no shape key animations, but the blinking one is constantly playing, regardless of other actions. Of course, that doesn't help me with the other facial expressions lol